# Problem when using jQuery prependTo method to move a Flash object

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery prependTo method to move a Flash ad box from the bottom of the page to near the top.  When I load the page, the ad box is now near the top of the page as expected, but when I scroll down to the bottom of the page, there is another ad box in the original position, which we don't want.

This is the code. The Flash advert is in a div class called MPU, and I'm prepending it to the .editorial div, which is near the top of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("div.mpu").prependTo(".editorial");
</script>
```

Can anyone suggest a way of getting rid of the superfluous Flash ad which still appears at the original position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach) the box first:

```
jQuery('div.mpu').detach().prependTo('.editorial');
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work.  When I use that code, the Flash ad just appears in its original position and doesn't get moved.  I've broken the code down into 2 lines, and it's failing at the detach() method - the div doesn't get removed and remains on the page.

Comment: Is your code wrapped into an document.ready event handler? e.g. `$(function() { jQuery('div.mpu').detach().prependTo('.editorial'); });`

Comment: It turned out that the content management system was linking to an old version of jQuery, and when I updated that the detach() method started working.  However, running the prependTo method in conjunction with the detach method is now giving me problems - when I load the page all that appears is 2 flash adverts, and the rest of the page isn't there! I'm not sure if this could be a problem with the CMS rather than the jQuery code.

Comment: Sounds a bit strange to me.. can you maybe provide an example / link to the page?